# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln{\left(x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}}{x} \; \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln{\left(x+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)}}{x} \; \mathrm{d}x$$
I tried $x=\sin{t}$ the symmetry with $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$ to get
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln{\left(\sin{t}+\cos{t}\right)}}{2\sin{t}\cos{t}} \; \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln{\left(\sin{t}+\cos{t}\right)}}{\sin{2t}} \; \mathrm{d}x$$

This looks much nicer I think but now what...? I considered $\sin{t}+\cos{t}=\sqrt{2} \sin{\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$ but that doesnt help.   Any hints or suggestions please.

Integral equals about 0.61685028